# Simple way to remove blank cells dynamic dropdown list Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Whenever I do a dependent dynamic drop down list , I see a bunch of blank cell in the drop-down list , I search many topics that explain how to remove them while   by adding two additional ranges like explained her http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/02/27/dynamic-list-with-blank-cells/

but my question is: Is there anyway to avoid blank cell or remove them using a simple approach without the need of two additional ranges or a complex formula?

the drop down list that contains blank cell  all I did is go to data validation and wrote in source `=MYCode` then I named the list that contains the codes like that `MyCode`and I checked ignore blank case (even tho It seems to be useless )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some more research I found a solution. In the cell where my information is filled I added a name using the name Manager and I added this formula that I adapted from [this article](http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-ignore-blanks-in-data-validation-list):

```
=DropList!$J$1:INDEX(DropList!$J$1:$J$10000,SUMPRODUCT(--(DropList!$J$1:$J$10000<>"")))
```

It did what I needed without the need of adding 2 extra cell, even though the line of code is rather complex.

Comment: I don't understand your solution.  Are you setting the above line of formula as the value for the dropdown list?  When I try to do that I get an error...

Comment: And what do you mean by you "added a name using the name Manager"?

Comment: Hello , If I remember properly , you don`t need to change anything , all what I actually did is this : ( depends on what version of excel you have) go to name Manager as explained in this picture https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/images/countifs004.gif than insert the formula above without changing anything but the name if your cell , for example let's say your data are in column A or B or C well instead of writing J change it to A or B or C ( depends on where your data are ) don't change the numbers

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I got it to work somewhat.  However, it seems this formula only removes blank cells from the END of the list.  To remove blank cells from the middle of a range of cells you need to make a new range of cells to filter the blanks out, as described in your link (http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/02/27/dynamic-list-with-blank-cells/).  With a combination of the two I was able to get a useful solution.

Comment: I think my problem was with blank cells at the end , sorry I couldn't guide you better because I did that last summer and It's hard to remember exactly , at least you solved the problem ! good luck

Comment: If I could upvote twice I would - this has saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

There is another way. Create a dynamically-expanding named range. Then use the range to define the data validation list.

To create your dynamically-expanding range, insert this in the named range box and give it a name:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1)
```

$A$1 should be replaced with the top cell of your range. $A$A should be replaced with the column(s) the range is in.

OFFSET points the named range at a range of cells. COUNTA() is in the fourth position of the OFFSET formula, which sets the height of the range. It counts the number of non-blank cells. As a result, when you add a value, the fourth value of the OFFSET formula increases and you get an expanding range.

Note, this does not work if your named range has blank cells interspersed.

OFFSET formula from [excel-easy.com](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html).

Comment: 2 years late but pure genius

Comment: Fantastic solution!

Comment: If you your first cell is A2 and not A1, subtract the COUNTA by 1 so that a blank is not added to  a dropdown

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is dead but I found a simpler solution which only requires you to create a single named range. It also works even if blank cells are interspersed in the source data, and expands as the source data expands.

First create your dynamically expanding named range using the formula given above:

> =OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1)

This will includes the values you want in your drop-down, as well as blank cells.
Next, in a separate cell, enter the following:

> =FILTER(Your_Range, Your_Range <> "")

The result will be your source data with no blanks. This will spill into adjacent cells. Now can reference this single cell as your data validation list, as long as you add "#" to the end of the cell reference. This tells excel to include all the spilled values in the list.

**Benefits:**

1. If your source data named range is dynamic, the drop-down list will expand with this range, and you don't have to worry about updating a second named range.
2. You can easily filter more data, and it doesn't matter if blank cells are interspersed.
3. Combined with the SORT and UNIQUE functions, you can further improve how your data is represented in the drop-down list.

I couldn't find a solution this simple anywhere else, so I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

If your dropdown list has blanks in them even though the source does not have.

i.e say if you set your validation source to be A:A to be dynamic and deleting a row from the source causes a blank in the dropdown

Here's another non formula way to create a dynamic dropdown without blanks in them

**NOTE**: This does not ignore an actual blank row in between the source

1. Convert your source list into a table. Your table can have unique headers
2. Go to Formulas > Name manager > New
3. Create a name for your named range
   i.e CarModels
4. In the 'Refers to' box type in =<*sourcetablename*>
   i.e `=Table1`
5. So now your named range should have the same value as the Table
6. For data validation, select List and the Source as =CarModels

Now if you add new items or delete row(s) from the table, the dropdown will reflect the source list without having annoying blanks in them

*Update : You dont even need to create a named range, you only have to convert the list into a table. In the data validation source box, hover the cursor at the table header till a black down arrow appears, click to highlight the table items (it shouldnt highlight the header). Your source box should look like this =$A$2:$A$4 ...It may look like a fixed range but its actually dynamic and behaves the same way as the named range

Answer (score 0):

If there are no empty cells **within** the source list, but the empty rows come from the **end** of the list, you can get rid of those by using a **table** as the source of the dropdown. You have to use the `INDIRECT` function to refer to the table:

- Select the whole source list including the header
- Click `Format as table`
- Select the table, go to the `Design` tab (under `Table Tools`)
- Rename the table
- Select the cells where you want to use the dropdown and open the `Data Validation`
- As the dropdown source, set: `=INDIRECT("TableName[ColumnName]")` (note the double-quotes)

[This article explains the procedure in more detail](https://blackatlascreative.com/blog/create-an-excel-data-validation-list-using-a-table/)