# Excel data validation not include blank cell error

Tags: vba, excel

I need to populate the data in data validation. I use below code for it.

```
Dim IntRow As Integer, IntLastRow As Integer
Dim Txt As String

With Sheet2

IntLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row


For IntRow = 10 To IntLastRow

    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(IntRow, 6)) Then


        Txt = Txt & .Cells(IntRow, 6) & ","
    End If
Next IntRow
End With

Txt = Left(Txt, Len(Txt) - 1)


With Sheet1.Range("E4").Validation

.Delete
.Add _
Type:=xlValidateList, _
AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:=Txt
End With
```

There are hundreds of data to insert in the drop down list. However there are blank cells between the data. This code works fine until I save it and reopen it again it will give an error. It automatically removes the data validation when repaired the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

There is a length restriction of 256 characters if you use a manual list. If you want more entries in your drop-down, you should refer to a range.

You can for example use your already existing column and ignore blank cells by following this:
[Simple way to remove blank cells dynamic dropdown list Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969520/simple-way-to-remove-blank-cells-dynamic-dropdown-list-excel)

Comment: The link you gave is to leave the blank cell at the bottom. Is there any direct way without the needs to create another column? Currently I am using the combo box, but I want to change to data validation if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Later in the link there is information on how to skip blank cells (http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/02/27/dynamic-list-with-blank-cells/) but it involves adding additional columns.