# Excel range without empty spaces

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I'm having trouble creating a dynamic range that does not contain any spaces (to be use for a data validation list). I have tried following this guide:

https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-ignore-blanks-in-data-validation-list

Found in this thread:

[Simple way to remove blank cells dynamic dropdown list Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969520/simple-way-to-remove-blank-cells-dynamic-dropdown-list-excel)

However, the result is not satisfactory and is merely a reflection (the empty spaces have not been removed). Please see picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/noMBF.jpg

The code I'm using (taken from the guide) is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100;SMALL(IF(ISTEXT($A$2:$A$100);ROW($A$1:$A$99)); ROW(A1)));"")
```

And I'm well aware that it is an array, hence I use ctrl + shift + enter and then drag it down. Still it is not working as expected... Any ideas?:/

Comment: your formula: `SMALL(IF(ISTEXT($A$2:$A$100);ROW($A$1:$A$99))` return `small ({row1, row2,0}, row (a1))`, let's try edit formula to result is:
`small ({row1, row2,10000}, row (a1))`, this is a way.

Comment: @TheGridLock, thank you for trying to help but I'm afraid I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: let's try: `IF($A$2:$A$100<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$99))`

Comment: if not using CSE,try to first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing going wrong is that `SMALL` is feeded just a simple `1` or `2`. While there are a lot of `0` values that get passed to `SMALL`. So you simply missing some way to exclude the `EMPTY` cells from your count.

You might be interested in a dynamic way to pull the last non-empty row into your formula (instead of hardcoding `A99` or `A100`). The below formula does work with a dynamic returned `Range`, in your case `A2:A40`. Put this in `C2` (**NO** CSE required):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(INDEX((A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1))<>"")*(ROW(A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1)))),),COUNTBLANK(A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1)))+ROW(A1))),"")
```

Basically:

- `MATCH("*",A:A,-1)` returns the row with the last **text**!
- `A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1))` returns a **dynamic** range > `A2:A40`
- `COUNTBLANK(A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1)))+ROW(A1))` will exclude all the empty cells to be returned to the `SMALL` index.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the educational answer! Unfortunately it just kinda works..? I'm so confused. Please see image on the following link: https://imgur.com/a/UdZ4W0c

Comment: @OmgAllCaps, insert the formula only in `C2`, then drag down....I works perfectly for me. Remember: This is for **text** values as per your examples!

Comment: Please check this photo, https://imgur.com/a/PgG1hVX . My apologies for my poor example. No matter how far I drag it, values past "Could" won't show up

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A;SMALL(INDEX((A$2:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("*";A:A;-1))<>"")*(ROW(A$2:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("*";A:A;-1)))););COUNTBLANK(A$2:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("*";A:A;-1)))+ROW(A1)));"")

Comment: Omg I just found the error. It would seem I had an empty space in one of the cells in Column A. Hence the code only worked up until that particular cell. It works flawless now. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. I'll make sure to go back now and learn from your first post:)

Comment: You are matching `""` which is nothing. I've lost track of your data and formula for now. Comments are not the place to keep going back and forth. So my advise, if you have new type of data, new layout, and a new formula, open a new question.