# Excel how get non-empty cells in range and using in validation dropdown list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am going to set a range to a defined name "Action" And set a dropdown list, but when my defined range got empty cells the dropdown list go incorrectly. I would like "Action" to skip empty cells and get all non-empty cells(ColorfulSnail_Shell, ColorfulSnail_Crash, StarWand). Is that possible? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is solution link to your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969520/simple-way-to-remove-blank-cells-dynamic-dropdown-list-excel

Comment: I will take a look, many thanks.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you, I succeeded!

Comment: Oh great, happy to know, glad it worked for you, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to remove blank cells dynamic dropdown list Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969520/simple-way-to-remove-blank-cells-dynamic-dropdown-list-excel)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes